# what's meaning of the source code "new CI;" in pyrocms?

Tags: php, pyrocms

I want to research the source code of pyrocms, and when I read the `Base.php`, I can't understand the following code

```
new CI;
```

the file is `system/cms/libraries/Base.php`

My problems are

1. why there has no a variable name, like `$CI = new CI`;
2. why it can be used as `CI::$APP->config->item('controller_suffix')` in it's sub class `MX_Controller` since there does not have variable name?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `CI::$APP` accesses a *static* field `$APP` of class `CI`. Static fields and members are properties of the class, not of its objects. `new CI` is probably done because of very poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This object isn't stored in a variable because it seems we don't need to manipulate it. On the other hand, look at its constructor: it does a lot of things (since it also calls the constructor of `CI_Controller`, which in turns loads a `Loader` and initializer it, ....)

So, we don't build it in order to manipulate it afterwards, but in order to run the code in its constructor.

2. We can use `CI::$APP-> whatever` because `$APP` is a static member, hence it doesn't require to have an instance of `CI` to be manipulated

Answer (score 0):

Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

[see statics on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)